# TypeScript compiler API: Print generic constraint with checker.typeToString()

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Is it possible to use `checker.typeToString()` in order to print a generic type constraint?

```
class Item {}
class Container<T extends Item> {
  public item: T;
}

const type = checker.getTypeAtLocation( /** AST node of 'item' property */ );
checker.typeToString( type ); // returns 'T'
```

I would like to see the return value `'Item'`. None of the `TypeFormatFlags` seem to cover this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the type and the constraints directly. You can get the constraint of the generic type and you can print the type of the constraint and putting it together with the `extends` keyword will get you what you want.

```
const type = checker.getTypeAtLocation( paramNode );
let constraintType = type.getConstraint();
if(constraintType == null) continue;
let genericType = checker.typeToString(type); // T 
let genericConstraintType = checker.typeToString(constraintType);  // Item
console.log(`${genericType} extends ${genericConstraintType}`); // put it together manually
```